# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

We all love [Spanish Language Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [¿Por qué cuando digo "Él no va a ningún lado" siento que está mal dicho?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5152/por-que-cuando-digo-el-no-va-a-ningun-lado-siento-que-esta-mal-dicho)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Duda sobre "escuálido" en el pronunciamiento de un Ministro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/duda-sobre-escualido-en-el-pronunciamiento-de-un-ministro)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [¿Es una ofensa decir "Chale"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/es-una-ofensa-decir-chale)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Equivalente de "discoverability" en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/equivalente-de-discoverability-en-espanol)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do I use two objects?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/how-do-i-use-two-objects)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [¿Es una ofensa llamar a alguien "ese"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/es-una-ofensa-llamar-a-alguien-ese)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to handle the ambiguity of the verb "presentar", when both objects (DO and IO) are present?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5027/how-to-handle-the-ambiguity-of-the-verb-presentar-when-both-objects-do-and-i)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [¿Cual es el uso de "bobo" en ciertos países?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/cual-es-el-uso-de-bobo-en-ciertos-paises)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [¿Valdurán o baldurán?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5140/valduran-o-balduran)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cómo se traduce apropiadamente "Bump a thread"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/como-se-traduce-apropiadamente-bump-a-thread)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---